# Django model instance left open

Tags: python, django, django-models

Could there be any problems in case Django Model instance is left open and not saved?

For example:

```
qs1 = Foo1.objects.all().first()
qs1.some_field = 'Bar1'

qs2 = Foo2.objects.all().first()
qs2.some_field = 'Bar2'
```

I was thinking of having **2** open instances of **2** different models which would have to be called in multiple cases. So instead of writing those **4** lines over and over again, could I simply define those like that and then just call `qs1.save()` and `qs2.save()` without having problems in future?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by - " would have to be called in multiple cases"

Comment: There are multiple `if` statements where depending on the outcome of those, would these instances be saved. @PankhuriAgarwal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider qs1 and qs2 as normal variable which would be written to database only when qs1.save() or qs2.save() is called.

Before save() is called no call is made to database and every value assignment will change the state of these variables.